# Cannot unify Navigation Bar Color from pre-iOS 7 application with new views added after iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar

As the title states; I have an application that was programmed pre-iOS 7 and there was an old navigation bar that used a certain color schema. I wanted to update this and I had added two new viewcontrollers to my storyboard; however whenever I hit global tint it only changes the two new storyboard additions that were made post iOS 7. Furthermore, I have done some research and tried putting:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar      = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navigationBar.tintColor             = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

within my AppDelegate to no avail.... thanks for your time

Comment: How was the colour set in the old controllers? Was it set via UIAppearance, in code, or in IB?

Comment: All there is is a gradient for the background with CAGradientLayer in the various viewDidLoad() of the classes; nothing using the UINavigationBar  anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use some of these methods for UINavigatioBar in app delegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
 // for making Translucent

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"article-list-picture-one"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
/// for making a navigation based on a image

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
//set a flat color of any know type
```

for more infomation check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494982/uinavigationbar-tintcolor-with-gradient)

Comment: Excellent post; I had just implemented that as you had typed it - should've done a little further digging. This worked! Thanks man.