# UIView hides Navigation bar back button text how to make it visible?

Tags: swift, ios7, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change Navigation bar background to Gradient Red.
I have added subview to navigation bar which sets background to Color I want.
but then Navigation bar back button Text is invisible.
Back button is visible but Text is not Visible.

```
UIView view = new UIView();
var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
gradient.Frame = NavigationBar.Bounds;
gradient.NeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true;
gradient.MasksToBounds = true;
gradient.Colors = new CGColor[] { UIColor.FromRGB(248, 0, 0).CGColor, UIColor.FromRGB(143, 0, 0).CGColor };
view.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradient, 0);
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { TextColor = UIColor.Clear });

var bounds = NavigationBar.Bounds;
this.NavigationBar.AddSubview(view);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created image out of gradient color and used that image as Background to NavigationBar. For iOS see below tutorial.

[UINavigationBar tintColor with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494982/uinavigationbar-tintcolor-with-gradient)

```
           UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(gradient.Bounds.Size);
           gradient.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
           UIImage backImage = Graphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
           UIGraphics.EndImageContext();      
           NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;
           UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(backImage, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```