# Make UINavigationBar have a gradient background using UIAppearance

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494982/uinavigationbar-tintcolor-with-gradient) question, I am able to make a background gradient for a `UINavigationBar`, however when I try to set it through `UIAppearance`, the app crashes in the `didFinishLaunching` because there is no current `CGContext`. How can I get around this and still have all my `UIAppearance` code in the app delegate?

The code being called just before `return true` in the `didFinishLaunching`:

```
private func setNavBarAppearance() {
    let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().makeTransparent()

    // Set gradient
    let colors = [UIColor.lavender.cgColor, UIColor.mint.cgColor]
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = UINavigationBar.appearance().bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    let image = UIImage(layer: gradientLayer)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
}
```

Comment: It may be a better solution for you to just subclass `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, you must provide a non-zero `CGRect`. In my case I was setting the frame to `UINavigationBar.appearance().bounds` which is a zero rect in the app delegate. To get around this I simply set the gradient `frame` to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1)`

Comment: This is brilliant, I come from Xamarin.iOS and this is the best approach.